# Dataset for IoT activities

Tags: dataset, research

First of all, I am not sure whether this is the correct Stackexchange site for this question. If not, please let me know :)

**My question**: I am looking for a dataset pertaining to IoT activities. Ideally, it should include network traces pertaining to the activity that a device was performing at a given time.
Here 'activity' means whatever the device was performing on behalf of a user

(e.g.: (Device,Activity): (Smart camera, Live streaming) | (smart switch: ON OFF activity)).

So far I could not find anything similar.
Can someone point me to something like this?

Comment: Please ask here https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!